# Retag / burninate the [spark] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

There is [Apache Spark](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/), a distributed computing engine, and there is [Spark](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_sparkintro.html), a component of Adobe Flex 4. People are tagging questions about both with [spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark), when they should instead be tagging them with [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark) or [spark-skinning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-skinning).

The [clear description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spark/info) on [spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark) does not appear to be enough to direct people one way or the other.

To avoid having to retag stuff constantly, I believe the appropriate procedure here is to retag existing [spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark) questions once and then <s>burninate the tag.</s> make the tag a synonym of [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark).

Comment: What do you mean by "burninate the tag?"  The way you do that is by removing the tag from each question, individually.

Comment: @rene: I created the synonym.

Comment: I think [tag:spark] and [tag:spark-skinning] are different things. Spark is the complete technology including skinning and actionscript. Retag and Burninate spark is not correct IMHO.

Comment: We could try to get an edit in the wiki of spark to redirect users to the apache-spark tag but such edits are better done by 20K plus because they go thrtough the suggedted edit queue otherwise.

Comment: @Robert - I always thought that "burninating" a tag meant somehow preventing people from tagging questions with that tag. If it just means retagging questions, then I guess I can take care of that, but I suspect the mis-tags will crop up again regularly.

Comment: @rene - I admit I am not familiar with Adobe Flex at all, so I'll take your word that Spark and Spark Skinning are different things. Certainly, neither one has anything to do with Apache Spark.

Comment: Is there a conclusion on this q? I was about to ask the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps an `adobe-spark` tag should be created, and all existing `spark` questions migrated to `apache-spark` or `adobe-spark` as appropriate? The existing situation is confusing, and the tag wiki for `spark` clearly state it's for Apache Spark.

Comment: @TreborRude - Yeah, that's a good idea. Basically, we need to make [tag:spark] a synonym in order to prevent future (inevitable) mis-tags, but before we can do that we need to migrate existing mis-tagged questions appropriately.

Comment: Just approved (oops) a suggested edit adding [spark] to a question already tagged [apache-spark].  Sorry for making life harder for you. Consider at least putting a warning in the [spark] excerpt.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - No worries. I think the long term solution is to make [tag:spark] a synonym of [tag:apache-spark] and retag any questions as needed.

Comment: Synonymized [spark] to [apache-spark] https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-spark/synonyms