# There is no [spark] but [apache-spark]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I do not have enough reputation to suggest tag synonyms, thus I am pointing one I found.
In my opinion the tags [spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark) and [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark) are synonyms.

Comment: The description says it is, but [spark] has a lot of questions that actually concern another meaning of the word. I'd say it's too ambiguous to make a synonym out of.

Comment: @StephanMuller Yes I know, but I think most of them (and the newest ones) are about apache spark. Somehow the meaning needs to be seperated. Maybe 'migrate' some question from spark to apache-spark and change the spark tag to spark-something. If the Moderators define a plan I am happy to help.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250936/retag-burninate-the-spark-tag

Comment: I agree with @Athafoud that some kind of one-time "migration" of questions followed by making [tag:spark] a synonym of [tag:apache-spark] is a good way to fix the problem of people mistagging stuff.

Comment: You can [vote on synonyms for `apache-spark` here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-spark/synonyms), but note that there are existing questions tagged `spark` that need to be retagged to `spark-skinning` or one of the other "spark" tags that got mixed up with Apache Spark.