# Cleaning up questions mistagged due to synonym creation

Tags: support

It looks like making [spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark) a synonym for [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark) resulted in a significant number of incorrectly tagged questions, most related to either [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) / [spark-view-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-view-engine) or [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) / [flex4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex4). In the second case situation is particularly confusing since it looks like Flex is an Apache project now.

I would like if there is any better way to handle situation like this than fixing tags one-by-one.

Comment: Well, I don't see any real feature that could be implemented by the Stack Exchange team to accomplish this... But you could write a userscript.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Do you have some examples where things got mixed up?

Comment: @rene Almost all questions from [page  455](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark?page=456&sort=active&pagesize=15) to 477.

Comment: Some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5203523/1560062, http://stackoverflow.com/q/15381297/1560062

Comment: This is the culprit that started all [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250936/retag-burninate-the-spark-tag)?

Comment: @rene It looks like it.

Comment: I try to find what Question Robert handled on my behalf, ah found it on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224432/please-make-spark-cluster-framework-a-synonym-of-apache-spark)